# Selenium Integration with HP ALM

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, hp-alm

I am starting to create a new Automation framework using Java. Ihave the requifment to integrate it with HP ALM. So far I have found a way using JACOB.

Can anyone suggest the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

We develop [Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee) product which allows you to upload Selenium test results into HP ALM.
Here is a link to the documentation: https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/qa-frameworks/selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Which one is the better way...using Bumblebee or ALM Service Wrapper or VAPIXP?

Comment: Being a Bumblebee developer I'm bit biased, but in my opinion, java annotations package provided by Bumblebee is the most convenient and fast way to integrate you selenium-based tests with ALM. We offer 14-days free evaluation, so you can just give it a try